# Vertical alignment of Fitch-style environment in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am trying to make a vertical alignment of a Fitch-style environment in a table. The package I use is *fitch.sty* and the code is given in [Selinger Fitch](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/fitch/fitch.sty). Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fitch}
\newcommand{\bsub}[2]{\boxed{#1}~{#2}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\peanoInduct}{
    \begin{nd}
        \have[~]{}{P(0)}
        \open
        \hypo[~]{}{\bsub{n}{P(n)}}
        \have[~]{}{P(s(n))}
        \close
        \have[\triangleright]{}{\forall x: P(x)} \by{PI}{}
    \end{nd}
}

\newcommand{\strongInduct}{
    \begin{nd}
        \open
        \hypo[~]{}{\bsub{n}{\forall x: x < n \rightarrow P(x)}}
        \have[~]{}{P(n)}
        \close
        \have[\triangleright]{}{\forall x: P(x)} \by{SI}{}
    \end{nd}
}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Peano Induction (PI) & Strong Induction (SI) \\
    $ \peanoInduct $ & $ \strongInduct $
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

whose result is

[image]

I want to make both Fitch environments aligned to the top of each cell. What is the systematic solution to this problem? I tried to apply the `makecell` with the option `[t]` to each cell in vain. It seems *fitch.sys* is using `array` internally. A method not using a table is OK.

**Edit:**

I found a solution. I add `[t]` option to the `array` environment in `\def` inside *fitch.sty* from

```
\def\nd*beginb{\begingroup\nd*reset\gdef\nd*stack{\nd*nil}\nd*push\nd*stack{\nd*t}%
  \begin{array}{l@{\hspace{\nd*labelsep}}l@{\hspace{\nd*justsep}}l}}
\def\nd*resumeb{\begingroup\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{\nd*labelsep}}l@{\hspace{\nd*justsep}}l}}
\def\nd*endb{\end{array}\endgroup}
```

to

```
\def\nd*beginb{\begingroup\nd*reset\gdef\nd*stack{\nd*nil}\nd*push\nd*stack{\nd*t}%
  \begin{array}[t]{l@{\hspace{\nd*labelsep}}l@{\hspace{\nd*justsep}}l}}
\def\nd*resumeb{\begingroup\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{\nd*labelsep}}l@{\hspace{\nd*justsep}}l}}
\def\nd*endb{\end{array}\endgroup}
```

How can I edit the style file to make this option attached to the `nd` environment so that I can choose the alignment for each case? For instance,

```
\begin{nd}[t]
    contents
\end{nd}
```